# Accessing weak_ptr after deleting the original pointer

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I get a runtime error when I execute the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    int value;
    Test( )
    {
        value = 1;
    }

    ~Test( )
    {

    }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Test> pTest =  shared_ptr<Test>( new Test( ) );
    std::vector<weak_ptr<Test>> testList;

    testList.push_back( weak_ptr<Test>(pTest) );
    cout << "\n Before Deletion";
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < testList.size(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            auto p = testList[i].lock();
            cout << "\n Item not null: " << p->value;
        }
        catch (bad_weak_ptr b)
        {
            wcout << L"Null object" << endl;
        }
    }

    pTest.reset( );

    cout << "\n After Deletion";
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < testList.size(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            auto p = testList[i].lock();
            cout << "\n Item not null: " << p->value;
        }
        catch (bad_weak_ptr b)
        {
            wcout << L"Null object" << endl;
        }
    }

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to find whether the pointer is still accessible (shouldn't be) after deleting the original shared pointer.

Comment: Please read the C++ FAQ item about ["How do I post a question about code that doesn't work correctly?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/posting-code.html). Even if that was written for a more technical forum than SO, it's still good advice also here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lock doesn't check for null, it promotes a weak_ptr to a shared pointer. It doesn't throw when the object is deleted, but rather returns null.

This is what you should be doing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    int value;
    Test( )
    {
        value = 1;
    }

    ~Test( )
    {

    }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Test> pTest =  shared_ptr<Test>( new Test( ) );
    std::vector<weak_ptr<Test>> testList;

    testList.push_back( weak_ptr<Test>(pTest) );
    cout << "\n Before Deletion";
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < testList.size(); i++)
    {
      auto p = testList[i].lock();
        if (p)
        {

            cout << "\n Item not null: " << p->value;
        }
        else
        {
            wcout << L"Null object" << endl;
        }
    }

    pTest.reset( );

    cout << "\n After Deletion";
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < testList.size(); i++)
    {
      auto p = testList[i].lock();
        if (p)
        {

            cout << "\n Item not null: " << p->value;
        }
        else
        {
            wcout << L"Null object" << endl;
        }
    }

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

To clarify, what happens when you to test_list>lock after  pTest is reset is you get a shared_ptr which contains NULL. and `((Test*)NULL)->value` is what happen when you do `p->value`, which is an obvious segfault.

The whole point of having a weak_ptr is to allow users the ability to safely get a reference to an object that may go out of scope. Exceptions would be a poor mechanism for this because exceptions are SLOW, and it is not necessarily a fatal error if the weak_ptr's parent goes out of scope. So the mechanism is lock either returns a new counted reference when promoted, or NULL if it can no longer promote the ownership level (the parent has expired).

Answer (score 1):

You could **[read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock)** instead of making assumptions about how things work.

`lock` does not signal nullpointer by throwing an exception: it returns a nullpointer.

So,

```
        auto p = testList[i].lock();
        if( p != nullptr )
        {
            cout << "\n Item not null: " << p->value;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n Item is null." << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My example was derived from this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279672.aspx

Comment: @ssk: The information given in that Microsoft how-to page (that `lock` throws) is incorrect, and the code is strongly misleading. Such how-to articles, or tutorials, are *not documentation*. Good tutorials (this was a very bad one) can guide you, but in addition you need to consult technical documentation.